# Vuex set state object default as object in array in state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

If I have in my store:

```
 state: {
     items: [],
     currentItem: {}
 }
```

and I want to select the first item on array as default currentItem:

```
 state: {
    items: [],
    currentItem: state.items[0]
 }
```

Which can't be done as state is undefined inside state.
I know that state has to be changed with a mutation. But if the state was a boolean I could set it for instance to false as default.

Is there a way to make it similar to the way I tried above?

Comment: In the code you listed `items[0] === undefined`.

Comment: it's not items that is undefined, is state. items array is defined and contains objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common JavaScript problem. It's not possible to refer to a property of an object that wasn't defined yet.

This requires to have temporary variable that stores a reference to reused object:

```
const items = [/*...*/];

...
 state: {
     items,
     currentItem: items[0]
 }
```

This can be done in-place in less readable way with IIFE if the context isn't suitable for temporary variables:

```
 ...
 state: (items) => ({
     items,
     currentItem: items[0]
 })([/*...*/])
```

Comment: I will accept this answer since is the closest one to what I was looking for. Although n my opinion is better set the default with a mutation..

Comment: I guess this depends on whether defaults are parametrized on commit or need to be set multiple times. In your case a mutation is likely preferable.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) value.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ["First Item", "Second Item"],
    index: 0
  },
  computed: {
    currentItem() {
      return this.items[this.index];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ currentItem }}
</div>
```

In a store you can use a [getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#getters) to achieve the same thing.

```js
  getters: {
    currentItem: state => {
      return state.items[state.index];
    }
  }
```

Comment: I need it as state in store, so if I had to follow this approach I would just create a mutation that sets the currentItem = state.items[0] and call the mutation in the component on mounted or created.  was just wondering if there is a simpler approach

Comment: Also because currentItem is changed in from several components, and there are getters depending on it

Comment: Or maybe in the mutations populating `items` you can set `currentItem`

Comment: Ah yes that's much better so it will be set only once items array is set as well